Is the overall (distinguishble-particle) ground state for a many-body identical particle Hamiltonian also immediately the bosonic ground state?
Consider the following many-body Hamiltonian of $N$ particles in an external trapping potential with inter-particle interactions:
\begin{align} 
\hat{H}= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla_i^2 + V(\mathbf{r}_i) \right] +\sum_{i<j} V(\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j) 
\end{align}
Assume for a moment that we are considering the "distinguishable" particle case where we do not care about symmetry and simply want to find the eigenstate $\phi_0^{(D)}$ with the lowest energy $E_0^{(D)}$. In other words we are trying to find the overall ground state in the space of all normalizable wave functions and are not imposing symmetry as a condition.
Will $\phi_0^{(D)}$ be also immediately the correct bosonic ground state? In other words, will the overall ground state that is found when not directly imposing symmetry be always a permutation-symmetric state?

May I ask why you guess so? (The answer is positive under certain assumptions, by the way--I can write an answer).

@TobiasFünke  It sounds reasonable that if the Hamiltonian is permutation-symmetric, then the density of the overall ground state should be permutation-symmetric unless there is some symmetry breaking. It follows that the distinguishable particle ground state is permutation symmetric up to a phase. It cannot be -1 since that creates nodes which seems like it should increase the energy, so it has to be +1. Therefore the distinguishable particle or the overall ground state should also be the bosonic one.

@TobiasFünke Very handwavingly, if it was the -1 case, then the wavefunction has to change sign multiple times and hence have a higher gradient term than the +1 one. Your answer is also welcome of course.

I see! I don't have much time right now, and I noticed that the proof is rather non-trivial. Let me refer to the reference I had in mind: Lieb and Seiringer, Stability of Matter in Quantum Mechanics, chapter 3.2.4. Hope this helps! If you google "Unrestricted Minimizers are Bosonic" you should find one or two other sources, which however also cite this book. The relevant passage in the said book should also be viewable in google books.

Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. The answer seems to be "very often this is the case"

Glad it helped! BTW: Very nice question. And if you find time, consider to answer the question your own (e.g. sketch the relevant parts of the proof), which might help potential future readers and might be of interest to other users, too. Sorry, but I really have not the time right now.
